# How to center a hyperlink in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working in this site

```
https://barrecertification.com/
```

In this page you will notice that YES — I Want to Get Barre Certified! just below the video.
It is centered with reference to the video, but when I zoom in or out the browser the centered position get lost and the position changes.

How to achieve the center position irrespective of the browser zoom level?

Comment: I mean to center under video not with respect to body

Comment: You could try to put them in a table with 2 rows: for your video and for the text.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your video and text element need to be contained in the same container. the reason your text moves is because it located on a separate row.

try dividing the row the text is on into the same as the row with the video.

Answer (score 0):

Move the hyperlink inside the div "responsive-video".

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <div class="responsive-video"
    //Your Video file src: 
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="#" class="your_class">YES I WANT TO....</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this markup. This should work. Avoid the whole `margin-left` and `margin-top` things from your class.